# Calculator_Switch JavaFundamental

Tags: java, eclipse, switch-statement, calculator

Hello I have tried syntax for calculator, with char for operand
but the result always error.
I'm using eclipse (Luna). there are no error or warning message on it.

> Syntax

```
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int answer = 0;
    System.out.println("Enter a number:");
    int num1 = in.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter another number:");
    int num2 = in.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter the operand:");
    char input =(char) in.nextInt();
    switch (input){
    case'*':
        answer = num1 * num2;
        break;
    case '/':
        answer = num1/num2;
        break;
    case '%':
        answer = num1%num2;
        break;
    case '+':
        answer = num1 +num2;
        break;
    case '-':
        answer = num1-num2;
        break;
    default:
        System.out.println("Invalid Command");
    }
    System.out.println("The result is: " + answer);
```

> Debugging

Input number, another number and an operand:

and the error:

InputMismatchException

Comment: In the line `char input =(char) in.nextInt();`, use `in.next()` instead of `in.nextInt()`

Comment: `in.next()` will give you a `String`...he's using a `char`

Comment: I have tried <code> in.next <code> there are error (cannot cast from String to char.

Comment: k, so when you use nextInt() it is trying to read in the value as an int. Then you are trying to use it as a char. This creates your InputMismatchException. Why not change everything over to String (including everything in your switch statement) and then use .next() as suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change this line: `char input =(char) in.nextInt();` for this `char input = in.next().charAt(0)`...and you are good to go!